# Problems with Set in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

So I need to write a function that basically prints out variables at risk and normal variables in a code, and I wanted to do it like this:

```
(*Names and Risk are of type Set(String)*)
let names=Names.empty
let risk=Risk.empty

let printRes names risk=
    if(Names.is_empty names=false) then printNames names else print_string "oops1";                                
    print_newline();
    if(Risk.is_empty risk=false) then Risk.iter print_string risk else print_string "oops2";
    print_newline();
;;    

let rec varsBlock (p:block) (ind:int)=
    match p with                                                                 
    |[]->printRes names risk
    |(line,instr)::r->match instr with
                      |Set(n,e)-> let names=Names.add n names in (); varsBlock r ind
                      |Read(n)->  let names=Names.add n names in (); varsBlock r ind             
;;
```

But the problem here is, every `Names.add` returns a whole new set, and my function `printRes` considers the set `names` (same goes for `risk` which is used in another function that follows the same pattern) as empty. Is there any other way of doing it without "obsuring" the original set I want to add everything to?

Comment: There are a bunch of style issues with your code. I could enumerate them, but rather I'd suggest you review the [OCaml Programming Guidelines](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/guidelines.html).

Comment: I know... I'll try and fix them, but OCaml is still quite new for me and after C and Java it's quite a change haha

Comment: It is quite a different way of thinking about programs. Make steady progress and read those guidelines to try to avoid getting into bad habits.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a global mutable variable I would suggest explicitly passing the `names` set to `varsBlock`. Then you can easily pass the updated set to the next iteration.

```
let rec varsBlock (p:block) (ind:int) names =
  match p with                                                                 
  | [] -> printRes names risk
  | (_, Set(n, _))::r
  | (_, Read(n))::r -> varsBlock r ind (Names.add n names)
```

Comment: May I suggest that nested `match` expressions are not necessary, nor is naming `line` in the pattern, as it is not used? These patterns should suffice: `(_, Set (n, e)::r` and `(_, Read (n))::r`.

Comment: Indeed. Also `e` doesn't need to be bound and the cases can be combined.

Comment: Ohh, thank you so so much, I will test it asap!!